# Como configurar una directiva Location en nginx para procesar ejemplo.com/(cualquier nombre)

Tags: php, nginx

Estoy montando un sitio en nginx, en la carpeta del sitio tengo una fichero
avatar.php, que dado un request avatar.local/{username} devuelve la imagen
asociada al username, el problema esta en como configurar en nginx que esta
url se resuelva de la forma que quiero, este es el bloque server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/avatar;
    index avatar.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.avatar.local avatar.local *.avatar.local;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/avatar_error.log crit;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/avatar_access.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

pero cuando intento una url avatar.local/manuel me devuelve un 404
alguien me podria ayudar a como resolver esto
gracias

Comment: prueba de añadir esto: `location / {
        rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ http://avatar.local$request_uri permanent;
    }`

Comment: Sería más bien `location / { rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ http://avatar.local/avatar.php?usuario=$request_uri permanent; }`